# Obtaining pointer to the base class of SWIG object

Tags: c++, python, callback, swig

I am using a library written in C++ and exposed to Python through SWIG. The class hierarchy looks like this:

```
PublicLib:
   MyBaseClass

PrivateLib:
   MyAbstractClass

   SomePrivateSubclass : MyAbstractClass, MyBaseClass
...
```

Note the multiple inheritance scheme here. Also, note that the classes in both PublicLib and PrivateLib are exposed to me as Python objects.

Now, I want to call a C++ function in another library, passing a pointer to one of the `SomePrivateSubClass` objects. The function looks like this:

```
void RegisterCallback(void* param);
```

Then, I expect that I will receive the object back through a callback, i.e.:

```
void SomeCallback(void* param) {
    MyBaseClass& cls = *(MyBaseClass*)param;
    cls.xxxx; // FAIL
}
```

The reason it fails is that the pointer I receive is not to the base class (`MyBaseClass`), but to one of the subclasses. In "normal" C++, I would do something like:

```
void RegisterCallback(MyBaseClass* param) { ... }

void SomeCallback(void* param) {
    MyBaseClass& cls = *(MyBaseClass*)param;
    cls.xxxx; // FAIL
}
```

and the compiler would take care of all this for me.

The question is, is there any way for me to obtain the pointer to the base class in this case? I can manipulate the code on the Python side, but there appears to be no way in SWIG to cast to the base class (that I can see). I also tried using RTTI, but it appears that although I can obtain the type identifier, I cannot obtain any other type information, such as the size or pointer to the base class.

Comment: What happens when you try to wrap three RegisterCallback function?

Comment: You mean one for each subclass? The problem is that the list of subclasses is (ideally) unknown to me.

Comment: Nope, just once for the Base. When calling RegisterCallback  it would cast to a pointer to the base, and then pass that as a void*. (Instead of a void* to the derived)

Comment: The problem is that RegisterCallback in the example above lies in another library altogether. I am trying to "glue" two libraries, with my C++ library only needing to know about the interfaces (abstract base classes) of the third party library.